# How to prove combinatoric identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How would you prove this identity using combinatorics? Any hints or advice?

For all positive integers $n>1$,

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1} {n\choose k} (-1)^{k+1}=\frac{-1}{n+1} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k+1}}
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{k+1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^{k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}(1-1)^{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=-\frac{1}{n+1}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}$.
- In (2) we shift the index to start from $k=1$.
- In (3) we apply the binomial summation formula and subtract $\frac{1}{n+1}$ as compensation for the lower limit starting with $1$ instead of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have:  $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{k+1}\cdot \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}\implies f'(x) = (1+x)^n\implies f(x) = f(0) + \displaystyle \int_{0}^x f'(t)dt = 0 + \displaystyle \int_{0}^x(1+t)^ndt = \displaystyle \int_{1}^{1+x}u^ndu= \dfrac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}|_{u=1}^{u=x+1}= \dfrac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}- \dfrac{1}{n+1}\implies f(-1) = -\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ .

Comment: Integrals? Why?!

Comment: Just give it a different opinion to solve it.

Comment: Interesting! (+1) :D

Answer (score 0):

**HINT 1:** Notice that
$$\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

**HINT 2:** Do you know the binomial theorem?

Comment: Yes i do, even have it out right in front of me right now

Comment: @A.Mercs I'm glad to hear it. Does this hint help?

Comment: Yes, somewhat. I'm assuming I can make the substitution in the LHS using hint 1, right?

Comment: @A.Mercs Yep, that's right.

Comment: OKay, so after doing that and moving some things around I've come to this: $\sum_{n}^{k=0} (k+1) {n\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} = \frac{-1}{n+1}$

Am I on the right track or did I go far with it?

Comment: Um... no. You should end up with
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{k+1}$$

Comment: So after fixing my blunder I have what you have but then you can take out a -1 which makes it $\frac{-1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{k}$

Comment: Aww, why the down vote?

Comment: I upvoted it, not sure why it got a downvote. Is there a way to make that $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ go away?

Comment: @A.Mercs You don't want it to go away... this is where you apply the binomial theorem.